# How to stop centering effect when using split equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

For example, the following code produces the equations below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{split}
    Helloworld & = A \\
               & = B
  \end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to know if it is possible to align left after using split equation

Comment: Do you want all displayed equations to be left-aligned, or just the ones that feature a `split` environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`amsmath` provides the `flalign` environment.  It is designed for placing two sets of aligned equations, the first block flush on the left margin, the second flush on the right, e.g.

```
\begin{flalign*}
  x & = A & y &= B
\end{flalign*}
```

produces

```
|x = A                                       y = B|
```

The first and third `&` here provide aligment points for the two blocks, the middle `&` separates the blocks.  The use of `flalign*` supresses equation numbers.

Placing your `split` in the first block, or simply before the first `&`, will thus make it align with the left margin.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Text before
\begin{flalign*}
  \begin{split}
    \textit{Helloworld} & = A \\
               & = B
  \end{split}&
\end{flalign*}
and after.
\begin{flalign*}
  x & = A & y &= B \\
  z & = C & u &= U
\end{flalign*}
Further text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Holy moly! That took me long to find this answer... Like hours!... More than two!... Thanks for sharing! :) For other desperate ones: *this is the answer! Place the last `&` !after! `\end{split}`*.

Answer (score 1):

Environment `multline` could be misused to place the `split` to the left, because the first line of `multline` is left aligned with indent `\multlinegap`, which can be set to zero. Then `split` needs to be changed to `aligned`, because `multline` prefers the latter.

Example with a horizontal rule to show the text width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\setlength{\multlinegap}{0pt}
\begin{multline*}
  \begin{aligned}
    \text{Hello world} & = A\\
                       & = B
  \end{aligned}\hfill
\end{multline*}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Depending on the material to be set, a `tabular` or similar might be an alternative.